# Unread Repeater field IMG alt not working

Tags: php, images, advanced-custom-fields

I've got a repeater field with images;

```
<?php
$produkt = get_field('produkte-startseite');
<div class="row start-products">

<?php foreach ($produkt as $produkte): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $produkte['url']; ?>">

        <div class="col3">
            <img src="<?php echo $produkte['bild']['sizes']['large']; ?>"
                 alt="<?php echo $produkte['alt']; ?>">

            <h3><?php echo $produkte['produkt-name']; ?></h3>
            <div class="overlay"></div>
        </div>

    </a>
```

And this is a little quote Code for var_dump of $produkte['bild']:

> aint(1024) } }  CROSSING array(24) { ["ID"]=> int(1764) ["id"]=> int(1764) ["title"]=> string(15) "crossing-starrt" ["filename"]=> string(19) "crossing-starrt.jpg" ["filesize"]=> int(200328) ["url"]=> string(74) "https://wwww.web.de/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/crossing-starrt.jpg" ["link"]=> string(50) "https://www.web.de/start/crossing-starrt/" ["alt"]=> string(5) "test1" ["author"]=> string(1) "1" ["description"]=> string(5) "test1" ["caption"]=> string(5) "test1" ["name"]=>

The problem is that I do not receive any alt text. But if I do var_dump it gives me as a result 4 arrays with 4 alt text.
Could someone help me?

Comment: What does your var_dump look like?

Comment: I have made a small quote of the var_dump

Answer (score 0):

You probably need `$produkte['bild']['alt']` instead of `$produkte['alt']`.